# Can not see newly moved files on USB

Tags: data-recovery, recovery-mode

I am using the newest LTS ubuntu and encountered some driver problems. Neverthless, the previous problems, new arise as folllwing:I entered an USB with 14GB of free space and from system recovery I entered the dropdown root terminal from where I used mv filename /media/sdx as.

I moved my Documents and Pictures and the total sum of these folders is well under 500 mb. So it is not the case of me pulling out the usb as I waited for some time.
Then after doing the mv to the usb I used /media/sdx to check if all the files are there. 
Now prev. when doing this the files that were several GB did not stay on the USB stick and I assumed that I had waited for too short amount of time, but now in this case my folders were well unde 500MB. Not even maybe 100MB.Did I make the same mistake again or is there anything I could do find the folders on my USB? 
The usb is ntfs. I can see other files.

Comment: I apologize, but your query made no sense to me. I would request you to share little more insight on it. You can take help of screenshots or web-links to make us understand in a better way.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? How did you mount the file system on the USB drive? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))